# Rename iOS application without xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I want to just rename an iOS project including the target file, executable file, plist file and product name without using XCode.

I have tried to manual renaming the ProjetName.xcodeproj but when I open the XCode only the XCode project name changed not the other files. I have closed the project and deleted the build folder. When I open the project in xcode and build again the Target file, executable file and product name are still with the old names.

How could I do it !

Thanks,
Easwar

Comment: The `ProjectName.xcodeproject` is actually a folder. If you access via Terminal, then can go inside and look at the XML (?) file. Modifying it from there is possible, but quite risky I may say.

Answer (score 1):

I've been doing some stuff like this for a while now, it can be done, but you gotta get crafty.

In the terminal go to the `yourApp.xcodeproj`(its just a directory you can cd into it)

Then using a text editor like Vim open the `project.pbxproj`

In that file you'll see the names of various parts of your project, ex `productName="yourAppName"`

that maps to the actual Variable `PRODUCT_NAME`, which will rename the app being built and the executable in it.

I haven't looked at everything in that file, because all I had to do was be able to change that, so that I could switch some files, change the name, use `xcodebuild`, and make it a hole new app ;)

but I'm willing to bet the names for most aspects of your project are in there and can be changed similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is possible. However you might try finding the .plist file and edit it and see if that works. Anyway...can't see any reason why you don't want to do this in xcode since evidently, you have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the xcproject has files that reference it where the project is, if you go behind Xcode's back to do this, your project just won't work.

You should use Xcode:

To rename your application, modify the Project Name field if you are using Xcode 4 or later or use the Rename feature if you are using Xcode 3.2.x.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1625/_index.html